# Python package Sympy: How to enforce that the adjoint of the identity matrix must be equal to the identity matrix

Tags: python, sympy

When I run this code

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(pretty_print=False)
I = sp.Identity(3)
A = sp.MatrixSymbol('A',3,3)
A*I
I*A
sp.adjoint(A)*I
I*sp.adjoint(A)
```

I get the expected results,

```
A
A
Adjoint(A)
Adjoint(A)
```

However, if I run

```
sp.adjoint(I)*A
```

I get

```
Adjoint(I)*A
```

Why doesn't Sympy replace Adjoint(I) by I ?

Answer (score 0):

`Adjoint(MatrixExpr)` doesn't evaluate, it is simply a symbolic object: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/matrices/expressions/adjoint.py.

So I assume `sp.adjoint(I)` uses lazy loading on any matrix to save on computation until it is actually necessary. Once the function is evaluated, then the adjoint gets computed and set to I.

Perhaps `I.adjoint()` does what you would expect.